# Passing an array to a React component and then accessing values within that array in the child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

working with React (but issue is Javascript I think) whereby I am trying to pass an array to a React component, and then within the child component (that consumes the array) - take values out of the array.

What I want to do is access the value: "_label" in my array. I've tried to do various versions of something like: `key._label` but to no success!

Parent:

```
      <StyledHorizontalAttributes>
        {objects[0].attributeCollection.questions.map((question) => (
          <FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant key={question.key} />
        ))}
        {console.log(objects[0].attributeCollection.questions)} // returns [StringAttributeModel (below)]
      </StyledHorizontalAttributes>
```

Child:

```
const FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant = ({ label, assistant, key }) => {
  return (
    <StyledGroup
      as={Row}
    >
      <StyledLabelWrapper>label</StyledLabelWrapper>
      {/* {isGroupedInput && ( */}
      <Column
        size={12}
      />

      <Column>
        <StyledAssistantWrapper>assistant</StyledAssistantWrapper>
      </Column>
    </StyledGroup>
  );
};
```

Array:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look like, you are trying to access the object `_contributions`**

Then you first need to put it into props:

```
<StyledHorizontalAttributes>
  {objects[0].attributeCollection.questions.map((question) => (
    <FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant key={question.key} {...question._contributions} />
  ))}
</StyledHorizontalAttributes>;
```

With that spread operator, you will have all the props from the `_contributions` object:

```
const FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant = ({ label, assistant, key }) => {
  return (
   ...
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yu forgot pass `label` to Child component:

```
<FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant key={question.key} label={question._label} />
```

And using `{}` to get value from `label`:

```
<StyledLabelWrapper>{label}</StyledLabelWrapper>
```